# Random video length

Tags: python, random, video, duration

I try to launch videos in a random order, with a random duration between 1 and 4 seconds for each video. I'm stuck with the random duration. I tried different things like for example using randint and randrage to get a random value for the intervall but I cannot find the way to fix that.. Anyone could help ?

```
import random
import time
import subprocess
import vlc
import os

# create list of all videos in folder 'videos'
subfolder = "videos"
videos = os.listdir(subfolder)

# specify clip length
intervall = (random.randint(1, 4))

# setup vlc instance
player = vlc.MediaPlayer()

try:
    print("Script running... press Ctrl+C to quit.")
    while True:
        # choose random file number
        n = random.randint(0, len(videos) - 1)

        # create path to current video file
        video = os.path.join(subfolder, videos[n])

        # get length of video n using ffprobe
        ffprobe = subprocess.check_output(['ffprobe', video],
                                          shell=True,
                                          stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

        # calculate length of current video in seconds
        i = ffprobe.find(bytes("Duration:", 'UTF-8'))
        duration = ffprobe[i + 9:i + 9 + 12].decode('UTF-8').strip().split(":")
        length = int(int(duration[0]) * 3600 +
                     int(duration[1]) * 60 +
                     float(duration[2])
                     )

        # create random position in video n
        position = random.randint(0, length - intervall)

        # feed player with video and position
        player.set_mrl(video)
        player.play()
        player.set_time(position * 1000)

        # wait till next video
        time.sleep(intervall)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

Comment: What is it exactly with the random number for `intervall` at which you are stuck?

Comment: When I run the code, the videos are launched in a random order but the duration is still the same for all videos. It seems like a unique value is chosen and applied for all the videos durations..

Comment: ```intervall``` is initialized once outside the ```while``` loop and used in every iteration. To use a new random duration for each video, move the initialization of ```intervall``` inside the loop.